# How can i create a loading screen like the below image in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimageview, uianimation

How can i create a animated loading effect like the below image in iOS. Any one kindly give me an idea or point me any examples. Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would use 2 UIImageViews.

1. An Image that includes these 6 small transparent circles (as holes) inside a blue box.
2. An image with a bigger white circle that moves behind the first image left to right repeatedly.

Comment: how u will do the animation?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a set of animation images, add them into array and then add into UIImageView.

```
NSMutableArray *imgArr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:n];
for (int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:(@"loadingImg%d.png",i)]];
[imgArr addObject:img];}
loadingImageView.images = imgArr;
loadingImageView.animationDuration = 1.0f;
loadingImageView.animationRepeatCount = 0;
[loadingImageView startAnimating];
```

loadingImageView - UIImageView, you can add it in XIB or in ViewDidLoad. n - number of images in animation.

Comment: small correction:
loadingImageView.animationImages = imgArr;